# Stop admin-ajax?

Tags: ajax, admin

Is it possible to simply disable/stop `admin-ajax.php` from running?

Have searched WordPress Doc. Have searched Google. Have searched this forum. Found no answer.

Have also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
function stop_ajax()
{
    define( 'DOING_AJAX', false );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'stop_ajax' );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "disable/stop admin-ajax.pl from running"? What should be done if such request is sent and it's disabled?

Comment: It's not clear if you're referring to wordpress heartbeat, but in this case, there are some good tutorials around the web explaining how to disable or better, how to limit it. This one is a good starting point https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/limit-heartbeat/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing [`admin-ajax.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php) does is define `DOING_AJAX`. Then, it loads [`wp-load.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-load.php). It does some other stuff, and the first thing it comes across that you have control over is `wp-config.php`.

So if you want to stop all ajax, you can add to following to your `wp-config.php` file.

```
if( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
  wp_die( '0', 400 );
}
```

If you don't have access to the `wp-config` file, or just want to do it via a plugin, you can do that too. No need to add it to a hook since if it's a request that doing ajax, it's already defined.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: Stop Ajax
 */
if( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
  wp_die( '0', 400 );
}
```

There will be side effects if you're using plugins or themes that require ajax, so be careful.